# Properly zooming a UIScrollView that contains many subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I created a zoomable UIScrollView and added 100 subviews to it (tiled). The view scrolls perfectly left and right. However, I'd like to allow zooming.

To do so I read that my delegate needs to implement:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return ???;
}
```

I have seen examples that have only one subview to zoom, so they return that subview in that method. In my case, however, I have a lot more. What is the proper way to do the zooming?

I tried creating another UIView and adding the 100 subviews to that one. And then return that one view on the method above, but I doesn't work (it zooms but once it stops, it's not interactive any more).

Comment: Have you tried returning the UIScrollView itself?

Comment: Yes, it was the first thing i tried. It messed things up as well...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Exactly,

This is what Apple also is mentioning in the [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html):

Just create a view, add all subviews to this view and add the newly created view as a single subview to the scrollview...

Then in the viewForZoomingInScrollView delegate method return the object at Index 0:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    return [self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created the view where I added everything using:

```
UIView *zoomableView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

without setting its frame.

The problem was solved when, after adding all the subviews to it, I set its frame to something large enough to accommodate all the tiled subviews.

Comment: worked for me too - setting the frame size of the father view to the maximum frame size of it's subviews (witch was the image size in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You have to return what your going to add views to scroll view as a subviews.

Ex: If you are adding image view to scroll view then write

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
return imageView object;
}
```